# How to append month names between dates in df and add rows for each month?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
        id   latitude  longitude  date_start    date_end
    111111  27.347346  70.078491  2011-03-14  2011-03-14
    222222  78.065875  71.373837  2011-04-13  2011-06-13
    333333  65.519341  66.987542  2011-06-04  2011-06-04 
...
```

and want my dataframe to look like this in the end:

```
        id   latitude  longitude  date_start    date_end      months
    111111  27.347346  70.078491  2011-03-14  2011-03-14  March 2011
    222222  78.065875  71.373837  2011-04-13  2011-06-13  April 2011
    222222  78.065875  71.373837  2011-04-13  2011-06-13  May   2011
    222222  78.065875  71.373837  2011-04-13  2011-06-13  June  2011
    333333  65.519341  66.987542  2011-06-04  2011-06-04  June  2011
...
```

In a first step I wanted to display all months between the dates in the columns. Therefore, I tried among others:

```
df['date_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_start'])
df['date_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_end'])
mts = pd.date_range(df['date_start'], df['date_end'], freq='MS').strftime("%B %Y").tolist()
df.insert(6, 'months', mts)
```

But I got the following error message:

```
Cannot convert input [...
Name: date_start, Length: 6282, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an intermediate function and use a combination of `apply` and a lambda to achieve what you'd like.

---

I first replicated your sample...

```
import pandas

df_string_dates = pandas.DataFrame({
    'id': (111111, 222222, 333333,),
    'latitude': (27.347346, 78.065875, 65.519341,),
    'longitude': (70.078491, 71.373837, 66.987542,),
    'date_start': ('2011-03-14', '2011-04-13', '2011-06-04'),
    'date_end': ('2011-03-14', '2011-06-13', '2011-06-04'),
})
```

...giving me this:

```
    id   latitude  longitude  date_start    date_end
111111  27.347346  70.078491  2011-03-14  2011-03-14
222222  78.065875  71.373837  2011-04-13  2011-06-13
333333  65.519341  66.987542  2011-06-04  2011-06-04
```

Next, I looked at the documentation for `date_range` and saw that it only takes strings or datetime-like arguments; unfortunately it seems we cannot feed Series into the function.

However, we can make use of an `apply`. First, we'll need to define a function which constructs the date range and converts it to a list, as you previously specified:

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Union

def ms_date_range_to_list(
    date_start: Union[str, datetime],
    date_end: Union[str, datetime],
) -> List[str]:
    return pandas.date_range(
        start=date_start,
        end=date_end,
        freq='MS',
    ).strftime("%B %Y").tolist()
```

Next, we can use the `apply` (similar to a `map`) to apply the function to columns of our DataFrame.

```
months: List[str] = df_datetime_dates.apply(
    func=lambda dataframe: ms_date_range_to_list(dataframe.date_start, dataframe.date_end),
    axis=1
)
```

Lastly, we can insert this into the DataFrame. Remember, columns are zero-indexed.

```
df_string_dates.insert(5, 'months', months)
```

Finally, we have:

```
    id   latitude  longitude  date_start    date_end  months
111111  27.347346  70.078491  2011-03-14  2011-03-14  []
222222  78.065875  71.373837  2011-04-13  2011-06-13  [May 2011, June 2011]
333333  65.519341  66.987542  2011-06-04  2011-06-04  []
```

---

A few things:

1. In your expected output, you show just one month for intervals containing two. I understood this to be a simple mistake on your part when typing out the expected input, and that you really do expect >1 months for some rows.
2. In your expected output, you show months as...strings? `tolist()` will, of course, return a list of strings. I trust you know how to extract or format strings from that list if you are wanting to save the output as a type other than list.